# Centos 6.7 sed replace text with string + char $

Tags: sed

for command sed, how can I replace text with string consist "$".

e.g. sed 's/ABCD60/$1$20ABCD'  where '$1$20ABCD' is a random string

Comment: have you try to escape the symbol?  sed 's/ABCD60/\$1\$20ABCD'

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see your problem.

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.7 (Final)
$ echo "ABCD60 ABCD60" |  sed 's/ABCD60/$1$20ABCD/g'
$1$20ABCD $1$20ABCD
```

Isn't this what you want?